# can't set dynamic classname in php

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $config = include APPPATH."email_config.php";

    $driver = "Email_".ucfirst(strtolower($config['driver']));   echo $driver.RT;  //gives Email_Smtp

   //   return new $driver($config); //do not work

   return new Email_Smtp($config);   //works
}
```

new $driver($config) gives the error message:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Email_Smtp' not found

$driver is the string "Email_Smtp".

return new Email_Smtp($config) works like a charm.
Whats wrong here?

the config file:

```
    return array(

        /**
         * Mail useragent string   wird in Header als X-Mailer:  gesetzt
         */
        'useragent' => 'my agent',

        /**
         * Mail driver (mail, smtp, sendmail, noop, php)
         */
        'driver' => 'smtp',
        ...
```

here is my autoload:

```
    class Autoloader {
    /**
     * @type string
     */
    protected $namespacePrefix = '';

    /**
     * @type string
     */
    protected $baseDir = '';

    /**
     * Sets the namespace's prefix.
     * Only classes with this namespace will be autoloaded.
     *
     * @param string $prefix
     * @return \Autoloader
     */
    public function setNamespacePrefix($prefix) {
        $this->namespacePrefix = $prefix;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the base directory, where we can find our php files.
     *
     * @param string $dir
     * @return \Autoloader
     */
    public function setBaseDir($dir) {
        $this->baseDir = $dir;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Register our autoloader.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
        spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
            if (!preg_match('/^' . preg_quote($this->namespacePrefix) . '/', $class)) {
                // Don't register a class without our namespace's prefix
                return;
            }

            $relativeClass = substr($class, strlen($this->namespacePrefix));

            $file = $this->baseDir . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $relativeClass) . '.php';

            if (file_exists($file)) { 

                require_once($file);

                // if the loaded file contains a class...
                if (class_exists($class, false))
                {
                    if (method_exists($class, '_init') and is_callable($class.'::_init'))
                    {
                        call_user_func($class.'::_init');
                    }

                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please show example of $config as well. maybe var_dump

Comment: Cannot reproduce   https://jdoodle.com/ia/6kf

Comment: Yep, i guess he has whitespace or something like this in the string

Comment: whats output of $driver === 'Email_Smtp' ?

Comment: if ($driver === 'Email_Smtp'){
  $output = "OK";
} else{
   $output = "wrong";
} gives =OK

Comment: Connot reproduce https://3v4l.org/9elWi . Maybe check for autoload or namespaces ?

Comment: @Syscall: you are right it has maybe something to do with my autoload.